# Create a Report in SAP Hybris to Fetch Employees based on a User Group

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

I need help for creating a report in SAP Hybris which essentially would be used for fetching out the names of "Employees" not "Customers" based on the "User Group" they're assigned. For example : X employee has usergroup : "admingroup". Like that I would need all the Employees with the respective usergroups. Could anyone please help me with a flexisearch query for the same to start with ? I would really appreciate that ! Thank you

I am still new to SAP Hybris and I have seen a lot of other reports but wanted to try this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `string_agg()`-method to list up the user groups, it's mentioned here: [How to concatenate multiple rows in flexibleSearch query in Hybris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363108/how-to-concatenate-multiple-rows-in-flexiblesearch-query-in-hybris)

If the method doesn't work you can try to replace it with `group_concat`.

You also need to join the `Employee` with the `PrincipalGroup`. You can access the employee's user groups with the attribute `groups`:

```
SELECT
{e:displayName},
string_agg({g:locName}, ', ') AS groupNames
FROM {Employee AS e}
JOIN {Employee.groups AS g} ON {g:pk} = {e:pk}
GROUP BY {e:pk}, {e:displayName}
```

Comment: so the g:locnames would separate out the groups based on the geographic locations ? also flexisearch shows that the "Employee.groups" is invalid. Any idea on why that could be ?

Comment: If `Employee.groups` is invalid you need to join via the relation table. You can look up the name of the required relation in the *-items.xml. As far as I understood `locName` stands for the localized name of the user group

Answer (score 0):

for this report it require join with PrincipalGroupRelation as there is no direct relation with usergroup and employee.

```
select {user_group:uid},{user_group:locname[en]},{emp.uid},{emp.name} from {Employee as emp JOIN PrincipalGroupRelation as group_rel ON
{group_rel:source}={emp:pk} JOIN UserGroup as user_group ON {user_group:pk}={group_rel:target} } where {user_group.uid}='customersupportagentgroup'
```